# ButtonHandler dont switch correctly

Tags: reactjs

The goal is therefore :
that after the first click the button is set to 'true', at the second click it calls the function and if it is already set to true it is set to false

I also have to declare the switch only with the `gameState`
and with an if I check if the value is false or true, but I don't enter my condition.

```
const handleClick = (gameState) => {
    switch (gameState) {
      case (gameState= 'tel') && (document.getElementById("Btn1").value= true):
          console.log('telbtnon');
          document.getElementById("Btn1").style.backgroundColor="#044b88";
          document.getElementById("Btn1").style.color="white";
          document.getElementById("Btn1").value= true;
    break;
    case (gameState= 'tel') && (document.getElementById("Btn1").value= false):
    if (document.getElementById("Btn1").value= false){
      console.log('telbtnoff');
      document.getElementById("Btn1").style.backgroundColor="transparent";
      document.getElementById("Btn1").style.color="#04b88";
      document.getElementById("Btn1").value= false;
    }
    }
}

//return 

 <div className='select'>
            <button id='Btn1' value={false} onClick={ () => handleClick('tel')} className='Button'>Télephonie</button>
            <button id='Btn2' value={false} onClick={ () => handleClick('share')} className='Button'>Partage</button>
            <button id='Btn3' value={false} onClick={ () => handleClick('security')} className='Button'>Securité</button>
          </div>
```

The first click must set the value to true, the second must set it to false